# Можно ли задать кодировку части текста в html?

Tags: кодировка, html, javascript

Интересует следующие:

Кодировка html задана как utf-8, но часть текста на странице в win-1251. Можно ли средствами html или js задать для этого текста кодировку win-1251 (или перекодировать в utf-8)
Например:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>UTF-8 текст</h1>
  <ul>
    <li charset="win-1251">Win-1251 текст</li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

С самим текстом в другой кодировке сделать ничего нельзя, можно только статично поменять "обертку" html вокруг.

Comment: Первый раз слышу, чтобы браузер отображал контент сразу в двух кодировках :)

Comment: Да я тоже, но есть такая задача. Может можно как-то js ом преобразовать? Есть шаблонизатор который генерирует по шаблону документ, шаблон поменять можно, а вот подставляемые данные - нет. А они часть на utf-8 часть на win-1251.

Comment: Думал над этим, спасибо. Попробую, но не уверен что получиться преобразовать в base64. Хотя наверное можно будет просто генерить iframe js'om.

Comment: @Чад я думаю, что и js'ом можно перекодировать. 

Вообще какая задача, такое и решение ;)

Comment: Не, походу перекодить не получиться js ом - при не правельной кодировке он в js попадает уже как '?'. Печаль.

Comment: А почему это вдруг текст нельзя перекодировать на стороне сервера? Если ваши инструменты не позволяют вам этого, смените их на нормальные.

Comment: :-) Пожелание из разряда "Если Вас не устраивает сервис отеля за который Вы заплатили на пол года вперёд, идите ищите другой отель, но деньги мы Вам не вернём" :-)

Во первых, мне интересно Возможно ли это (разные кодировки в одном файле).
Во вторых - нельзя.

Comment: @Чад: Ну, как это нельзя? Напишите wrapper на источники данных. Если это база данных, перекодируйте данные в ней. Измените код шаблонизатора. Всё в ваших руках, что за упадничество?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@Чад](/users/7390/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4)](/users/7390/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4) наверно можно часть с другой кодировкой вынести в iframe? Т.е. получается:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>UTF-8 текст</h1>

  <iframe src="data:text/html;base64,PGh0bWw+CjxoZWFkPgogIDxtZXRhIGNoYXJzZXQ9IldpbmRvd3MtMTI1MSIvPgo8L2hlYWQ+Cjxib2R5PgogIDx1bD4KICAgIDxsaSBjaGFyc2V0PSJ3aW4tMTI1MSI+V2luLTEyNTEg0YLQtdC60YHRgjwvbGk+CiAgPC91bD4KCjwvYm9keT4KPC9odG1sPg=="></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А можно как нибудь добавить данные фрейма без кодировки base64?

Comment: @Чад конечно можно:

    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>UTF-8 текст</h1>
      
      
     <iframe id='frame'></iframe>
     
     <div id='hide'>
      <ul>
       <li charset="win-1251">Win-1251 текст</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     
     <script>
     document.getElementById('frame').src = 'data:text/html;charset=win-1251,' + encodeURI(document.getElementById('hide').innerHTML);
     </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: Нет, похоже, это не возможно. Жаль.

Comment: @Чад хмхм, а попробуйте вставить фрейм с ссылкой на эту же страницу, замените charset и из фрейма удалите всё ненужное! Вдруг проканает!

Answer (score 0):

Можно заранее перекодировать текст в цифры, если строка уже известна, например так:

`"Привет" -> "&#1055;&#1088;&#1080;&#1074;&#1077;&#1090;"`

Мне помог сайт https://magictool.ai/tool/html-decoder-encoder/ru/